# I get an object does not support method error when code that is listed tested

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub test()

    Dim Tbl As Table
    Set Tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

    Tbl.Cell(2, 2).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture "C:\users\user\desktop\Flower1.jpg"
    Tbl.Cell(2, 2).Range.InlineShapes(1).Select
    Selection.InsertCaption Label:="Figure", Title:=" : Caption Flower 1", _
                            Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow
End Sub
```

Used in Excel(MS365), VBA code is used to create a word document and inserts a table. Picture is inserted but the code fails at the Selection.InsertCaption method (Error 438, object doesn't support this method). I am not a fan of using selection but the cell(2,2).range.insertcaption puts the caption below the table instead of below the picture in the cell.

Comment: Your code isn't working as Excel has its own Selection. Qualify with Word.Selection.InsertCaption etc. Then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Don't assume that the number of your object is `1` because that is unlikely. Luckily for you, the `.AddPicture` method returns an object handle. You also need to define captions before you insert them.

Like so:

```
 Sub test()

    Dim Tbl As Table
    Set Tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

    Dim labelName As String
    labelName = "Figure"
    CaptionLabels.Add Name:=labelName 

    Dim newPicture As Object
    Set newPicture = Tbl.Cell(2, 2).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture("C:\users\user\desktop\Flower1.jpg")
    newPicture.Range.InsertCaption Label:=labelName , Title:=" : Caption Flower 1", Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow
End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Think you need newPicture.RANGE.InsertCaption. Also if you declare newPicture as Word.InlineShape (rather than Object) you get the early-binding and IntelliSense.

Comment: Thanks @DS_London, I have updated the code to include that and a line to add the caption label before it is inserted. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.captionlabels

Comment: I also found that adding a reference to the word application object before Selection at enforces VBA to identify the selection as a word selection.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions , very helpful.